# How to create customize layout placement of part item for orchard query layout

Tags: orchardcms, projection

I've manage to generate the List.cshtml shape for rendering the list of content items, in my case this content item has a Title(text), Description(text), hyperlink and Image. So I want all this part to be rendered base on my expected layout, all part such as Title, Description and hyperlink is okay but when I tried to render this Image part there is no path of the image. where and how do I get this piece of information as long this image can be rendered in the view.

Expected layout.
[image]

Orchard default layout 
[image]

Code for List.cshtml:

```html
@{
    var contentItems = new List<Object>();

    if (Model.Items != null)
    {
        contentItems = Model.Items;
    }

}

<div class="main-post">
    <div class="container">

        @foreach (var mainContentItem in contentItems)
        {

            var targetContentItem = (Orchard.DisplayManagement.Shapes.Shape)mainContentItem;
            var listOfShapes = targetContentItem.Items.ToList();

            var title = listOfShapes[0];
            var desc = listOfShapes[1];
            var mediaLib = listOfShapes[2];
            var actionLink = listOfShapes[3];

            <div class="clearfix hidden-xs" style="height:40px;"></div> <!-- spacer -->

            <row>

                <div class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs">
                    <figure>
                        @mediaLib.Item
                        @*
                            <img src="@mediaLib.Item" class="animation animated animation-fade-in-left" data-animation="animation-fade-in-left">
                        *@
                    </figure>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <div class="col-text">
                        <div class="post-heading-left">
                            <h2>@title.Item</h2>
                        </div>
                        <p>@desc.Item</p>
                        <button onclick="window.open('@actionLink.Item')" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">View App</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </row>

        }
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What is your exact question. How to retrieve the image url?

Comment: Yes how to retrive the image url from the shape object and is there any method to override the query layout with a custom layout